# Invertible $R$-module, $R$ local ring, $L \cong R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, schemes

In the last 5 lines of [Lemma 17.22.4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01CR), the author seems to claim:

> If $L$ is an invertible $R$-module, and $R$ is a local ring, then $L \cong R$.

The algebra section doesn't address this case. How is this true?

Comment: IIRC  invertible modules are projective. All projective modules over a commutative local ring are free.

Comment: It would be helpful to include your definition of invertible. For instance, Eisenbud (*Commutative Algebra*, $\S11.3$) defines an invertible module $M$ to be one that is (stalkwise) locally free of rank $1$, i.e., $M_P \cong R_P$ for all $P \in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$. This makes the answer almost immediate. See also https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B8I, although here the definition of locally free is slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last statement of Lord Shark the Unknown can be found also in stacksproject, [10.84.4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/058Z). Let me elaborate on the first part. I recall this from a lecture notes of Vivek Shende.

As $M$ is invertible then exists $N$, $M\otimes_R N \cong R$, hence some $m_i \in M, n_i \in N$, $\sum m_i \otimes n_i =1$. There is a surjective map

$$ R^k \otimes N =N^k \rightarrow M \otimes_R N \cong R, \quad  (s_i) \mapsto \sum m_i \otimes s_i$$
As $R$ is free, $R^k \otimes N = R \oplus Q$, tensoring by $M$, yields $R^{k} = M \oplus Q ' $ so $M$ is projective.